# Set theory composite function proof

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

The question is:
Let $g:B \to C$ and $h:B \to C$ be functions. Assume that $g \circ f=h \circ f$ for every function $f:A \to B$. Prove that $g=h$.

Here is my attempt

$g=h$ if and only if $g(b)=h(b)$   $\forall b \in B$

Consider some $b \in B$ such that $f(a)=b$ for some $a \in A$.

$g(b)=(g \circ f)(a)=(h \circ f)(a)=h(b)$

However, I have not assumed for an arbitrary $b$ so, it does not prove it. How should I fix the problem?

Comment: @Sil Yes, sorry, I edited it.

Comment: Who is $A$ ? You have a universal quantifier in front of $A$ so at some point you will be bound to choose an $A$. You need to choose $A$ and $f$, and then you'll manage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $A$ is the empty set, then the theorem is false. So, assume that $A$ is not empty.

Now, we need to prove that for every $b \in B$, we have $g(b) = h(b)$.

Fix an arbitrary $b \in B$.

To do this, we firstly construct the function $f$ such that $f(a) = b$ for every $a \in A$.

Fix an arbitrary $a \in A$.

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
g \circ f &=& h \circ f \\
(g \circ f)(a) &=& (h \circ f)(a) \\
g(f(a)) &=& h(f(a)) \\
g(b) &=& h(b)
\end{array}$$

Comment: If you're allowed to vary over any function $f:A\longrightarrow B,$ then couldn't you consider the case where $A=B,$ and $f=id_B$? Then the two functions would define the same relation in $B\times C,$ and therefore be the same function.

Comment: @Justin Oh, i didn't know I can vary $A$ also....

Comment: I believe you can. This is only true because it says "for every function $f:A\longrightarrow B.$" I suppose it comes down to how pedantic you want to be about what a function $f:A\longrightarrow B.$ If you're allowed to vary $f,$ then you should be allowed to vary its domain, at least up to a Set isomorphism.